# Pandas adding extra zeros to decimal value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a file into pandas dataframe but the dataframe is not retaining original values as is, instead its adding extra zero to some float columns.

example original value in the file is 23.84 but when i import it into the dataframe it has a value of 23.8400

How to fix this? or is there a way to import original values to the dataframe as is in the text file.

Comment: Please show an example of the source data as well as the corresponding clip of the DataFrame you believe to be incorrect.

Comment: Those numbers represent the **same value**. The representation of a number in a text file may be different than how the interpreter chooses to display them. For instance, in a text file you may see, `1.31884812E-01`, and when loaded into an dataframe, `0.131884812`.. those are the same value.  If you want to print out your dataframe in a specific format, you'll have to convert the values to strings to customize their representation for reports or whatnot. Appending 0's to a float value is common.

Comment: I understand that the interpreter decides how to display them but I dont want the interpreter to add those extra zeros. Because if these are really extra zeros in the file thats not acceptable for my use case. So I'm unable to say if these are extra zeros in the file itself or the zeros introduced by the interpreter.

Comment: Adding the solution I found to this problem, for anyone who encounters the same problem. Pandas read_csv has an attribute as dtype where we can tell pandas to read all columns as a string so this will read the data as is and not interpret based on its own logic.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters the same problem, I'm adding the solution I found to this problem. Pandas read_csv has an attribute as dtype where we can tell pandas to read all columns as a string so this will read the data as is and not interpret based on its own logic.

df1 = pd.read_csv('file_location', sep = ',', dtype = {'col1' : 'str', 'col2' : 'str'}

I had too many columns so I first created a dictionary with all the columns as keys and 'str' as their values and passed this dictionary to the dtype argument.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same situation, but didn't want to generate the dttype dictionary by hand for a large data frame. So I looked up the command for generating the existing dict and replacing "float64" with "object".

```
# Get The Current Datatypes of the Columns
str(df.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.name).to_dict()).replace("float64", "object")
```

The output of this you then can use as value for the dtype argument in read_csv()

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file_location', sep = ',', dtype = <DictionaryString>)
```